How do I solve a "linked-server error" when using execute(@sql) at [linked_server] when the server is already registered?
I have a requirement to link to an Oracle server in the cloud through a linked server in Sql Server.
I have created a stored procedure to execute a generic PL/SQL script that returns an IEnumerable<T> list using Dapper with a stored procedure call.
The stored procedure is:
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Oracle_s] 
(
    @sql varchar(4000)
)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @result bit = 0;
    set nocount on;
    declare @temp nvarchar(4000) = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LK_VPROD, ''' + REPLACE(@sql,'''', '''''') + ''')';
    
    begin try
        exec sp_executesql @temp;
        --execute(@sql ) at [LK_VPROD];
        set @result = 1;
    end try
    begin catch
        SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage; 
        set @result = 0;
    end catch
    set nocount off;
    return @result;
END

When I use it with the sp_executesql coding, it produces the right result.
When I use it with the execute(@sql) at [LK_VPROD] coding, it returns either "server is not found in sys.servers" or most recently "Server 'LK_VPROD' is not configured for RPC."
I am assuming it's a configuration issue for using the execute at version of the SP because the other version works fine.  I want to use the execute at version because I don't want to construct the sql script for openquery.
What am I doing wrong here?
I have tried changing the configuration of the linked_server to no avail.  It still works with the openquery-based constructed script but still fails with the execute at script.
Here are the server options:


What does: select is_remote_login_enabled, is_rpc_out_enabled, is_data_access_enabled,  * from sys.servers where name = 'LK_VPROD' return

is_remote_login_enabled is_rpc_out_enabled is_data_access_enabled
0 0 1

The SP as listed above works, but if I uncomment the exec at section and comment out the exec .. @temp line, it fails.

What happens if you turn them on by using ssms gui?

How do you turn them on by using gui?

what kind of program are you using to run queries. If it's SSMS, go to Object Explorer -> Server Objects -> Linked Servers -> right click on server name and take properties, and select Server Options

See some screenshots here: https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-and-configure-a-linked-server-in-sql-server-management-studio/ You should activate RPC and RPC out

That was the problem.  I tried setting RPC without success.  I needed to set RPC Out as well.

As https://stackoverflow.com/users/13061224/siggemannen pointed out, I needed to set both RPC flags.
I didn't want to mess around too much with the server settings because it is on our production server even though I haven't been using the linked server.
